He is breaking up with you (FUTURE)
SEE THE LINK HERE
Context: The mother in the video is talking with her son's girl friend. She know her son well that every time he invite a girl to their home, the son is going to dump that girl soon.

The mother: (1a)He is breaking up with you.
The girl: (2a) It is not happening.

As I see, the mother and the girl is predict an immediate future.
How about these sentences? :
(1b)He will break up with you.
(1c)He is going to break up with you.
(2b) It won't happen.
(2c) It isn't going to happen.
Is that we can use present continuous to predict about the future when we are completely sure that will hapen?

You're overthinking the temporal precision. When the mother says He's breaking up with you she's talking about a relatively extended process, not a single action that takes place at a moment in time. That process has already started, even though the girl is unaware of this, and thinks of it as a "future" event that can be denied and/or prevented. In short, the ongoing / impending breakup is both present and future, depending on your perspective. The verb tenses used by both speakers are perfectly natural for Anglohones in such contexts.

How about the version with “will “ and “be going to”

(1b)He will break up with you.
(1c)He is going to break up with you.

I think that I also can use the other versions. But what is the difference between them?

All your alternatives carry subtly different implications from the actual words used. For example, 1b will emphasizes the inevitability of the breakup (regardless of whether it's perceived as "ongoing" or "future"). 1c forces the "future" perspective, 2b tends to underline the girl's determination to prevent the breakup, and 2c conveys denial that the breakup is or will be happening. But these are subtle points that not everyone would agree on, and/or either deliberately make when speaking, or understand when hearing.

If so, I can use any of them, the difference is so small. As a learner, I shouldn’t care about which one to choose. Right?

"The mother and the girl are predicting an immediate future".

@KateBunting I know this, I thing I want to ask is that if I can use other form to predict this immediate future in this context

Yes - as a learner you shouldn't really need to concern yourself with the possible subtle differences. What matters to you is you need to recognize that English can be exceptionally flexible about verb tenses, so you should pay more attention to the specific context, and less to the literal implications of a choice of tense. Especially in conversational contexts. As an example, you might like to consider I was in the pub last night, and this bloke comes up to me and says "Oi! Did you spill my pint?"

...but we're not that flexible! Every native Anglophone will wince at your second sentence, which should start with She knows her son well [enough to realize] that every time he invites a girl to their home...

@FumbleFingers  I was in the pub last night, and this bloke comes up to me and says "Oi! Did you spill my pint?"==> All the words in bold "was" "comes" "say", Can we mix the tense like this "was" is past tense, " come" and "say" is present tense.

@FumbleFingers Every native Anglophone will wince at your second sentence==> which sentence?

@FumbleFingers so you should pay more attention to the specific context, and less to the literal implications of a choice of tense. ==> do you mean that a specific context determines the verb choice. Right?

LE123, I was correcting your English - 'They are predicting', not 'is predict', and in the sentence that  FumbleFingers mentioned 'She knows', not 'she know'.

It's true that very often the precise choice of verb native speakers make in contexts such as the one we're looking at can be influenced by very specific nuances. Sometimes deliberately because of an impression the speaker wants to convey, sometimes without the speaker being consciously aware of why he chose one verb form over another. I set out possible reasons for 4 different choices in my earlier comment. But I didn't mean that you should devote any attention to learning or using such variations yourself. Just accept that precise meaning from native speakers my ignore "literal" meaning.

...devote effort to getting basic verb conjugations right - so you won't have to keep being corrected by others!

@FumbleFingers kate Bunting thanks so much for both your help

The mother is treating it as if the breakup is already in progress, based on her experience with her son. Inviting the girl over is the first step in the process. So she uses the present progressive to describe an action that's currently happening, and the girl responds similarly.
It would be reasonable to treat the breakup as not happening until the boy actually tells the girl that he's dumping her. In that case, they would use the future tense. We would usually use "going to" in situations like this:

Mother: He's going to break up with you.
Girl: No, he won't.


How about “He’ll break up with you.”

That's a prediction, but it suggests that it will happen some indefinite time in the future, not immediately. It's often used as part of a conditional: "If you do X, he'll break up with you."
